# A game based on cutting rectangles from paper

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, dynamic-programming

You are given a piece of paper that consists of $w \times h$ squares. You can cut the sheet in a vertical or horizontal axis at the positions with integer coordinates so that the paper becomes two separate sheets. $A$ and $B$ play the game as follows: If you cut out the $1 \times 1$ sheet you will be the winner. $A$ is the first to cut.

For example:

- $w=2,h=2$. The result is $B$, because firstly, $A$ has to cut $2 \times 2$ paper into $2$ sheets have size $1 \times 2$. Then $B$ chooses the $1 \times 2$ sheet to cut it into $2$ sheets have size $1 \times 1$. So $B$ is the winner.
- $w=4,h=2$. The result is $A$, because $A$ can cut into $2$ sheets have size $2 \times 2$. Next, $B$ is forced to cut $2 \times 2$ sheets into $2$ sheets have size $2 \times 1$. We have $2$ sheets have size $2 \times 1$ and $1$ sheet have size $2 \times 2$. A just needs to select $2 \times 1$ sheet and cut it to win.

My problem is how to determine which of $A$ or $B$ will win in the general case.

This is my try:
  First of all, I think this problem relevant to parity of $w$ and $h$.

- If $h=1$ or $w=1$. A is always win.
- If $h>1$ and $w>1$. We will consider the parity of $w$ and h.
  Firstly, if $h=2$ or $w=2$, soppose that $h=2$.
- If $w=2$. We will have $B$ is the winner.
- If $w>2$ and $w\equiv 1(\text{ mod }2)$. I will get some examples for this case:
- With $w=3$ we will have $A$ win.
- With $w=5$ we will have $A$ win.
- With $w=7$ we will have $B$ win. Because A will separate the sheet $2x7$ into 2 sheets $2x3$ and $2x4$, then B will seperate the sheet $2x4$ into 2 sheets $2x2$ and $2x2$. Finally, B is the winner.
- With $w=9$, similarly ,we will have $A$ win.
- With $w=11$, similarly, we will have $A$ win.
  So I can't see the pattern in this case!!!

Ps: I see that with any case $w>1$ and $h>1$, every turn, cutting is relevant to 2 sheets are $2x2$ and $2x3$. And I want to build recursive from that.

Comment: Any board with an even dimension greater than $2$ is a win for A-he can cut it in half and win by symmetry.  $2 \times 3$ and $3 \times 3$ are wins for B as A must cut a width 1 strip.  $3 \times 5$ is a win for A because he can cut $2 \times 3$.

Comment: A board with an even dimesion greater than 2, it means $w$ and $h$ are even numbers? @RossMillikan

Comment: Either one is enough.  From $6 \times 7$, say, we can cut two $3 \times 7$ boards.  Then if B cuts a width $1$ strip A can cut the $1 \times 1$.  Otherwise A can mirror B's move on the other $3 \times 7$ and not have to cut a width $1$ strip.

Comment: So, in the case $3x5$ may be the special case, because there is no even dimension, but A is win! @Ross Millikan

Comment: Based on my comment two ago, the only interesting boards are $2 \times$ odd and odd $\times$ odd.  Yes, $3 \times 5$ is a win for A.  I haven't figured out others.

Comment: How many of these are you going to post, know dont, before you figure out how to solve them on your own?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I'm really thank you for your comment, I will edit my post!!!.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,@Ross Millikan I editted my post !!!. I added some my effort about this problem and my stuck!!!

Comment: @RossMillikan, I see that the case 2x7, A will be winner!!

Comment: Many games like this are covered in Winning Ways by Berlekamp and Conway.  A fabulous (now 3 volume) book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the answer when we restrict the shorter side to be $2$ or $3$.  In these cases, no one will ever want to divide the cake lengthwise, for that leaves a $1xn$ strip, so we can just consider a game where we divide a $1\times n$ strip.  (Note that $2\times 2$ is a winning position if and only if $3\times n$ is a winning position.)

In this new game, you lose if you make a $1\times 1$ square (since in the "real" game that corresponds to leaving a $2\times 1$ or $3\times 1$) so in the new game we will say that you must leave at least $2$ squares in each of the rectangles, and you lose if you cannot make a move.  At this point, the rectangular structure becomes unimportant, and we can just think of dividing a pile of counters into two piles of at least two counters each.

This is a nim-like game that can be analyzed by the [Sprague-Grundy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem).

I wrote a python script to do this for $n\leq100.$

```
'''
Divide a pile into two piles, 
each of size at least two'''

def mex(n):
    values = set()
    for k in range(2, n//2 + 1):
        values.add(M[k]^M[n-k])  # nim sum
    for k in range(0,n):
        if k not in values:
            return k

M= { }
M[1]=M[2]=M[3]=0
for n in range(4,101):
    M[n] = mex(n)

print([k for k in range(1,101) if M[k]==0])
```

The script prints a list of all the losing values for $n\leq100,$ and it doesn't look promising.

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 11, 17, 23, 27, 31, 37, 41, 45, 57, 61, 65, 75, 79, 91, 95, 99]
```

This coincides with [A274161](https://oeis.org/A274161) (for $n>1$) for which the formula "The sequence consists of $\{2,3,17,37\}$ along with all positive integers congruent to $7, 11, 23, 27,$ and $31$ modulo $34$" is given.

It's easy to see that the edge-delete game on $P_n$ described in A274161 is the same as the "new game" I described above.  I didn't think of checking OEIS until I was about to press the "Post your answer" button, but I decided to leave my analysis in because it seems clear that the general game can be reduced to a nim-like game in a similar fashion.

Comment: After read your post, I see that if $w,h\in \left\{2,3,7,11,17,23,...,99\right\}$ then $B$ is always win!!!. How do you feel? @saulspatz

Comment: Fortunately!!! I have got accepted when use it!! Amazing!!

Comment: @knowdont Can you prove this?

Comment: @knowdont I've verified this computationally for $w,h\leq250$ so I believe it.  Still thinking about a proof.

Comment: So, We can prove as follows: Suppose $w$ and $h$ are not simultaneously in the above set, it will happen two cases: $w*h\equiv 0(\text{ mod }2)$(it means either $w$ is even or $h$ is even ) and $w*h \equiv 1(\text{ mod }2)$(it means $w$ and $h$ are odd and $w,h\notin\left\{2,3,...,99\right\}$). In 2 two case, we always prove that: $A$ always wins.

Comment: @knowdont Well, yes you can verify for $w,h<100$ by computation.  I meant a proof for arbitrary $w,h$